# git pull remote branch V/S git merge remote/branch V/S git rebase remote/branch

Tags: git, repository, git-merge, git-rebase, git-pull

Consider my forked repo is mapped with the remote `origin` and the parent repo mapped to `upstream`.

Seems like, all the 3 commands below can be used to keep the `master` branch of `origin`, up to date with the `master` branch of `upstream`.

```
git pull upstream master

git merge upstream/master

git rebase upstream/master
```

Please help me understand if there are any differences between these three commands.

Comment: `git pull` *means* "run `git fetch`, then immediately run a second Git command", typically `git merge` but if you choose in advance you can specify `git rebase` instead. So `git pull` is `git fetch` *plus* one of the other two commands. For beginners, I recommend avoiding `git pull` entirely: start with `git fetch`, then run the other command yourself. Everything will make more sense this way.

Answer (score 1):

The output of merge and pull is the same in the sense that changes from the merged branch is applied on top of current commits in your current branch.

Before pull /merge

```
  A---B---C master on origin
 /
D---E---F---G master
```

After

```
  A---B---C origin/master
 /         \
D---E---F---G---H master
```

The output of rebase is reverse of pull. All the new commits from the point the current branch is created is shelved. The commits from the remote branch is applied and then the local commits are applied. So compared to pull the local commits are at the end of commits of remote.

```
     A---B---C topic
     /
D---E---F---G master
```

After rebase command

```
              A'--B'--C' topic
             /
D---E---F---G master
```

Source - https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase